# Testing for a ValidationError in Django

Tags: django, django-unittest

If I have a model called `Enquiry` with an attribute of `email` how might I check that creating an Enquiry with an invalid email raises an error?

I have tried this

```
def test_email_is_valid(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, Enquiry.objects.create(email="testtest.com"))
```

However I get the Error

> TypeError: 'Enquiry' object is not callable

I'm not quite getting something, does anybody know the correct method to test for email validation?

Answer (score 8):

Django does not automatically validate objects when you call `save()` or `create()`. You can trigger validation by calling the [`full_clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method.

```
def test_email_is_valid(self):
    enquiry = Enquiry(email="testtest.com")
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, enquiry.full_clean)
```

Note that you don't call `full_clean()` in the above code. You might prefer the context manager approach instead:

```
def test_email_is_valid(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        enquiry = Enquiry(email="testtest.com")
        enquiry.full_clean()
```

Comment: ValidationError can be imported with
`from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError`